# jQuery call a function from outside a custom function

Tags: jquery, custom-function

Maybe I didn't word it correctly. But I have a custom jQuery function I created. Now outside of the function, I want to be able to call one of its internal functions.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/dmcqe1fj/

In the jsFiddle example I have two simple textboxes. The custom function will confirm if their text matches. I want to access a function within that function.

*Note: I know that I can achieve the same result by simply testing equivalency outside the function, but I am specifically looking to see how you call an internal function from outside of the custom function (if its possible)*

```
$(function() {
  
  $.fn.Test = function() {
    const $master = this;
    
    const $t1 = $master.find(".txt1"),
          $t2 = $master.find(".txt2"),
          $notice = $master.find(".notice");
    
    function Check() {
      $notice.removeClass("error success").hide();
      if ($t1.val().length === 0 && $t2.val().length === 0) {
        return;
      }
      if ($t1.val() == $t2.val()) {
        $notice.addClass("success").text("Text Matches!").show();
      }
      else{
        $notice.addClass("error").text("Text Does Not Match").show();
      }
    }
    
    $t1.on("keyup", Check);
    $t2.on("keyup", Check);
    
    /****** THIS IS THE FUNCTION I WANT TO ACCESS ********/
    function GetResult() {
      return $t1.val() == $t2.val();
    }
    
  };
  
  let $test = $("#container").Test();
  
  $("#btn").on("click", function() {
    console.log($test.GetResult());  // This is not valid
    
    /*
      I know the same result can be achieved:
          console.log($(".txt1").val() == $(".txt2").val());
       
      BUT I AM SPECIFICALLY LOOKING TO SEE HOW 
      TO CALL A FUNCTION WITHIN A CUSTOM FUNCTION
    */
  });
  
  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a more "object oriented" approach to your function:

```
function parentFunction()
{
    this.childFunction = function(){
        return 'hello world';
    };
}

var $test = new parentFunction();

console.log( $test.childFunction() );
```